# Parallelising MapReduce

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I am new to Parallel Programming and Hadoop MapReduce. The following example was picked up from Tutorial website.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm

How to parallelise MapReduce (apply parallel programming) to Mapper and Reducer so it can run together and how to introduce multithreading to it?

Is it possible to run Mapper on one machine and Reducer on other at the same time?

Apologies if I wasn't able to explain very well.

```
 package hadoop; 

 import java.util.*; 

 import java.io.IOException; 
 import java.io.IOException; 

 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.*; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.util.*; 

 public class ProcessUnits 
 { 
   //Mapper class 
   public static class E_EMapper extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Mapper<LongWritable ,/*Input key Type */ 
   Text,                /*Input value Type*/ 
   Text,                /*Output key Type*/ 
   IntWritable>        /*Output value Type*/ 
   { 

      //Map function 
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,   
      Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
      { 
         String line = value.toString(); 
         String lasttoken = null; 
         StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,"\t"); 
         String year = s.nextToken(); 

         while(s.hasMoreTokens())
            {
               lasttoken=s.nextToken();
            } 

         int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken); 
         output.collect(new Text(year), new IntWritable(avgprice)); 
      } 
   } 


   //Reducer class 
   public static class E_EReduce extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Reducer< Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > 
   {  

      //Reduce function 
      public void reduce( Text key, Iterator <IntWritable> values, 
         OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
         { 
            int maxavg=30; 
            int val=Integer.MIN_VALUE; 

            while (values.hasNext()) 
            { 
               if((val=values.next().get())>maxavg) 
               { 
                  output.collect(key, new IntWritable(val)); 
               } 
            } 

         } 
   }  


   //Main function 
   public static void main(String args[])throws Exception 
   { 
      JobConf conf = new JobConf(ProcessUnits.class); 

      conf.setJobName("max_eletricityunits"); 
      conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 
      conf.setMapperClass(E_EMapper.class); 
      conf.setCombinerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setReducerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class); 
      conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class); 

      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0])); 
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1])); 

      JobClient.runJob(conf); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you explained very well, but I am struggling at the same hadoop level so I will read the answer of the post with pleasure

Comment: @gen.Strash. Yeh sorry, I tried to explain it properly but due to not having much knowledge got in the way. Let’s hope we get some answers

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop will take care of parallelizing the work for you; you shouldn't need to do anything other than run the hadoop jar.

Regarding mapreduce in general, you should keep in mind that the `map` phase and `reduce` phase occur sequentially (*not* in parallel) because `reduce` depends on the results of `map`. However, you can have several `mappers` operating in parallel, and once those finish, several `reducers` in parallel (depending on the task of course). Again, hadoop will take care of launching and coordinating those for you.

[image: mapreduce phases]